# Testfirst.org - Learn ruby course - Rspec issue unresolved

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to do the testfirst.org exercises although can't seem to get to the starting line due to a version issue/lack of knowledge on my part as well..

At the begining you have to run the test $rake

i got following error..

```
(in /home/arno/learn_ruby)
rake aborted!
Gem::MissingSpecError: Could not find 'rspec' (~> 2) among 94 total 
gem(s)
Checked in 
'GEM_PATH=/home/arno/.gem/ruby/2.4.0:/home/arno/.rbenv/
versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0', execute `gem env` for more 
information
/home/arno/learn_ruby/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I then tried to uninstall rspec.  I then tried to install a version less than 3. That also did not work. Now I have version 2.9 and 3.2 installed but the same error persisted..

I then did bundle install and bundle update...something changed although still not working..

Here is the latest error when i run the test $rake..

```
(in /home/arno/learn_ruby)
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `last_comment' for #
<Rake::Application:0x00564ff13bf4b0>
/home/arno/learn_ruby/Rakefile:8:in `new'
/home/arno/learn_ruby/Rakefile:8:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is the rakefile..

```
# This Rakefile has all the right settings to run the tests inside 
each lab
gem 'rspec', '~>2'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

task :default => :spec

desc "run tests for this lab"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|
  lab = Rake.application.original_dir
  task.pattern = "#{lab}/*_spec.rb"
  task.rspec_opts = [ "-I#{lab}", "-I#{lab}/solution", '-f 
documentation', '-r ./rspec_config']
  task.verbose = false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of searching i found a solution from The Odin Project.

They have a Test First - Rspec 3 edition..

If your having the same issue go to their repo https://github.com/TheOdinProject/learn_ruby.

Read through the readme file, fork that repo, clone your version of the repo, cd into it and bundle install..

All works fine now..